# ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE permission on Android ICS

Tags: android, permissions

I declared the permission `ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE` in Application manifest as below.

```
<uses-permission  android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

Everything is good on Android 2.x. But on Android ICS, it failed with below log cat.

```
 java.lang.SecurityException: ConnectivityService: Neither user 10093
 nor current process has android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE. at
 android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1327) at
 android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1281) at
 android.net.IConnectivityManager$Stub$Proxy.getActiveNetworkInfo(IConnectivityManager.java:663)
 at
 android.net.ConnectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.java:455)
 at com.tapfortap.AdView.getNetwork(AdView.java:146) at
 com.tapfortap.AdView.loadAdsWithAppId(AdView.java:133) at
 com.tapfortap.AdView.access$100(AdView.java:47) at
 com.tapfortap.AdView$1$1.run(AdView.java:88) at
 android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605) at
 android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92) at
 android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) at
 android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4503) at
 java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) at
 java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) at
 com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:809)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:576) at
 dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: At which place in your Manifest did you place the <uses-persmission>-Tag?

Comment: try clean and rebuild your project, and uninstall previous build from your device and test again

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I updated the permissions like this and it works.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

this is because ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE is used as connectivityManger and this needs INTERNET connection.

Comment: This cannot be a valid answer. Your update to the manifest probably just triggered a clean build or something like that.

Comment: I don't know why, but That's steps to resolve my issue. I think that this is a bug of android SDK, and Android SDK teem should fix it.

Comment: what happens when you remove the last line from your snippet? if it breaks again, that would be strong indication of a bug. if it does not, the "clean build" explanation from @Makibo wuold be so much more likely. PS: forget it, i just saw that the answer is 2+ years old...

Comment: I ran into this issue Android Studio. The changes to the manifest was not picked up, and only a clean/rebuild resolved it.

Comment: As stated by @Makibo, this cannot be valid. It should be the triggering of clean build that resolved the issue. Just clean build or clean cache and restart Android Studio.

Answer (score 11):

I believe this is an issue with Eclipse; it fails to refresh the manifest to load the permission.

I had the same problem as the original poster and solved it by adding the permission a second time--but then I was able to remove the permission without affecting behavior. This makes me suspect that Eclipse didn't load permissions correctly until I touched the file.

Answer (score 10):

Just add the below permission and it will work fine, i had this a problem before and resolved with me

```html
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Answer (score 3):

Clean and then Build project solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 2):

Uh-oh,If u adding by default,it will be:

```
<uses-permission android:name="ANDROID.PERMISSION.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

if u re-add permission by:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

It works fine.
Unbelievable ! It costs me 2 days

Answer (score 2):

you are missing the Internet permission.add this permisssion it will correct your problem

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just cut the `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />` and paste all the above permissions. It will work fine...

Answer (score 1):

Clean Project. Check the manifest file. Some package name changes or misplaced data may causes this error.

Clean the project will work.

Comment: if you use android studio, this issue will not come. +1

Answer (score 1):

In your code, There would be places where you would be checking the Internet Availability before making your calls so that your app doesn't crash at runtime. For that, you have to access the '**NETWORK STATE**' which requires the permission :

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>`

And when the Internet is available, your device communicates with the server using the '**INTERNET**' which requires the permission :

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`

Answer (score 0):

In my case, neither **Clean Project** not **Rebuild Project** worked, and I spent hours to figure out how to get rid of this lint error.

I was also afraid to use the final option **Invalidate Caches and Restart** because I might roll back to any Local History of a file in future, in case any bug arises.

So finally, I opted for the following option.

1. I chose **File->Invalidate Caches and Restart**.
2. It opened a popup. I then selected the option **Just Restart**.

And guess what!!It solved my problem. So if any of you are still struggling to get rid of this error, you might wanna try my solution. Do let me know if it worked.