# Android ConnectivityService "Neither user 10052 nor current process has android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE."

Tags: android

I have a report of this exception even though I have the permission in the manifest:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(1215): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{****}: java.lang.SecurityException: ConnectivityService: Neither user 10052 nor current process has android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE.
```

---

```
Manifest.xml

<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="****"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

     <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="11" android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

<application>
    ....
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: "A" report, as in singular from a device in the field,  could well be from a customized android build with selective runtime permission blocking.  Can you check that it works on a stock device of the same Android API version?

Comment: What AOS version are you running. Not enough info here...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try rebuilding your project (clean, build).
If it doesn't help, you can try this a bit weird solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12778460/1993204) that seems to be working.

Comment: I fixed my problem doing what the link said, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `minSdk` and `targetSdk` from manifest file and add it to the `gradle.app`, like below.

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.2'
    defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.demo.demo.activity"

    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 22
    versionCode 37
    versionName "4.1.8"

    multiDexEnabled true
}
```