# TelephonyManager crashing on android studio

Tags: android, telephonymanager

I have shifted my eclipse code to android studio and I tried executing the project on studio and it crashes on  TelephonyManager. I have created the old code on Theme.Holo.Light .

I have added permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>


<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<!-- Required to show current location -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
```

Class:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        final TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        final String tmDevice, tmSerial, androidId;
        if (tm.getDeviceId() != null) {
            tmDevice = "" + tm.getDeviceId();
            tmSerial = "" + tm.getSimSerialNumber();
            androidId = "" + android.provider.Settings.Secure.getString(getContentResolver(), android.provider.Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);
            UUID deviceUuid = new UUID(androidId.hashCode(), ((long)tmDevice.hashCode() << 32) | tmSerial.hashCode());

            String appdeviceId = deviceUuid.toString();

            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),appdeviceId,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }


}
```

Logcat:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ava.lang.SecurityException: Neither user 10101 nor current process has android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE.
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
     Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Neither user 10101 nor current process has android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE.
            at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1546)
            at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1499)
            at com.android.internal.telephony.ITelephony$Stub$Proxy.getDeviceId(ITelephony.java:3692)
            at android.telephony.TelephonyManager.getDeviceId(TelephonyManager.java:624)
            at example.com.telephoney_manager_test.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:24)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had pasted the permissions below the application tag . I pasted the permissions above application tag and everything is working fine.

Answer (score 10):

I had this topic with Android Studio (1.4 Beta 4) and a Nexus 6 running an Android M preview.

I could fix the problem by running the app once (receiving an exception), then going to Settings -> Apps -> My app -> Permissions which showed (Surprise,  surprise!) all requested permissions and all permissions were turned off.

I then turned on all permissions manually and started the app from Android Studio again. Since then the permission problem has disappeared.

Answer (score 2):

If you're targeting API 23, then you need to request any runtime permissions, which from your manifest are:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

This is true every time you reinstall your app, which can be tedious.

Your options:

1) Install with the "-g" option. This will grant all permissions you ask for that you are reasonably allowed to have.

```
$ adb install -g myapp.apk
```

2) Grant the permissions you need at runtime using the PackageManager:

```
$ adb shell pm grant com.myapp "android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this permission in manifest

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
```

Comment: Spend some time to read the question.. he already have this permission

Comment: You shouldn't get this error than. Are you using Eclipse, sometimes it doesnt read the permission good. Try change smth in manifest and rebuild

Answer (score 0):

So you already mentioned in your question you already have the  `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />` permission. It means does n't happen !!

I think unfortunately your android studio is unable to build the project properly.  it fails to refresh the manifest to load the permission.

So, Try to  rebuilding your project (clean, build). If it doesn't help, you can try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12778168/access-network-state-permisson-on-android-ics/12778460#12778460) a bit weird solution from here that seem to be working.

As a **Note**  Check the entire manifest file. Some package name changes or misplaced data/names may causes this error.

Comment: I tried but it's still not working. There something in the manifest file. Can you think of few reasons .It could be styles also .I checked that and it works fine when I test only telephonyManager test but it crashes in the app.Any ideas ??

Answer (score 0):

If you're targeting API 23, then you need to request any runtime permissions. Here is a workaround for the issue: change the file of build.gradle, change the value of targetSdkVersion below 23.