# User does not have android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE

Tags: android

My app is crashing on launch with this error. I've got the permissions in the Manifest, so I'm not sure what is going on.

```
    --------- beginning of crash
06-14 09:50:31.638 2550-2550/com.rebeccafuller.movienight E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                            Process: com.rebeccafuller.movienight, PID: 2550
                                                                            java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.rebeccafuller.movienight/com.rebeccafuller.movienight.ui.MainActivity}: java.lang.SecurityException: ConnectivityService: Neither user 10074 nor current process has android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE.
```

Here is my Android Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.rebeccafuller.movienight">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".ui.MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Make sure you're editing the correct `AndroidManifest.xml` file and not one of the intermediate build ones in the build folder

Comment: Maybe you've already seen this, but other programmers have reported solutions involving a complete clean and rebuild of the project, and/or adding the ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE permission twice. I'm not making this up: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12778168/access-network-state-permisson-on-android-ics/12778460#12778460

Comment: Depending on the api level of the device you must implement a runtime permission asking. This was done to improve security and from api 23 is needed to ask them at runtime. 

Take a look to developers at https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html?hl=en

Comment: @Ivan, this is clearly not an API 23 runtime permission issue, If it is API 23 kind of issue, it will throw exception clearly mentioning that to initialize runtime permission and its callback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove permissions and try clean and build.. It will get crash again.. then add these 3 permissions again and execute.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
```

it will solve your problem